# How can I handle or detect a system signal in D?

Tags: signals, d

D's (rather sparse) official documentation doesn't have anything about handling system signals on *nx or Windows.

The `system` module only has `Endian` and `OS`, `syserror` is deprecated / only for Windows errortext, and `signals` is about message-passing, not system signals.

Is there a way (in pure D) to install a signal handler, to capture and allow me to react to certain signals at runtime, or, at least a way to detect that a signal was recieved and an exception I can `catch`?

i.e, in Python, a simple example is:

```python
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGSEGV, myFunctionToHandleSEGV)
# ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same as in C, just with an import instead of an include. Find a C example that looks interesting to you, then change `#include<signal.h>` to `import core.stdc.signal;` if you are using just the standard C `signal` function, or `import core.sys.posix.signal;` if you are using Posix functions like `sigaction`, then remember to mark your callback (if you use one) with `extern(C)` (and in recent versions of D, `@nogc nothrow` too), and then the rest of the code should compile as D the same way as in C.

Comment: what harm may I have if I omit `@nogc nothrow`?

Comment: It won't compile. But if you define the C function yourself without them, you can make it compile, but still, you aren't supposed to do much of anything from a signal handler, so either of those operations brings you to undefined behavior anyway (likely going to crash you, eventually) so might as well just play by the rules.

Comment: I do realize that I cannot throw exceptions in a signal handler. My question was not what happens if I throw an exception, but what happens if I do not specify `nothrow` (or `@nogc`) modifier

Comment: And I answered that: "it won't compile, but if can define the C function yourself without them,you can make it compile."

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You say something about something that either will or will not compile. It is all I understand

Comment: Do you mean that it compiles with old but not with recent versions of D?